# Writing Tests for real time applicaitons using SignalR

Tags: docker, unit-testing, automated-tests, real-time

I have a question about writing tests for SignalR.
I'm developing a chat application right now using **C#** and **AspNetCore** and **SignalR**.
my frontend is written in flutter
and I just provide APIs to get called and SignalR Hub functions to get invoked and also invoking some functions on front-end side.

**is there a recommending way to write tests rather than just mocking in unit tests?**

for example is it a good idea to bring up all dependencies with docker and test if my **ChatHub** is working properly?
I'm asking this because all the time my frontend says that something on server side is not working properly and then I should test my release on stage server by bringing up a console app (using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client)
which acts as the client and test the stage server like that.

if you could help me I would really appreciate it.